# Python: How to filter columns from a csv data within a webpage?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, urllib

My current implementation is:

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f=urllib.request.urlopen('<my_url_goes_here>')
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())
my_csv = csv.reader(soup.pre.text,delimiter=",")
for row in my_csv:
    print(row)
```

I want to print out my data in the following format:

```
//datestamp,SvcName,AvgSvcTime,MinSvcTime,MaxSvcTime,SvcVol
2013-03-19 00:00:00,cfmeqdequeue,1,0,10,198
2013-03-19 00:01:00,cfmeqdequeue,1,0,10,198
2013-03-19 00:02:00,cfmeqdequeue,1,0,10,198
```

However, the actual output looks like this:

```
['c']
['f']
['m']
['e']
['q']
['d']
['e']
['q']
['u']
['e']
['u']
['e']
```

Note: `soup.pre.text` prints the following and has the proper newlines:

```
'\n//datestamp,SvcName,AvgSvcTime,MinSvcTime,MaxSvcTime,SvcVol\n2013-03-19 00:00:00,cfmeqdequeue,1,0,10,198\n2013-03-19 00:01:00,cfmeqdequeue,1,0,10,198\n
```

So something must be wrong when I use csv.reader() or the for loop.

Comment: csv.reader function accepts a parameter which represents a **delimiter (in your case its comma), parse the csv using delimiter and your problem should be solved.Go through the documentation for help http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Added the delimiter parameter. Revised question completely to show the current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `csv.reader` a string.  [Or something close enough -- I can't remember if `.text` gives a string or one of bs4's stringlike objects.]  It needs a filelike object.  You can use the `StringIO` module to get a string to behave like a file to get around this.  For example, you have

```
>>> import csv
>>> s = '\n//datestamp,SvcName,AvgSvcTime,MinSvcTime,MaxSvcTime,SvcVol\n2013-03-19 00:00:00,cfmeqdequeue,1,0,10,198\n2013-03-19 00:01:00,cfmeqdequeue,1,0,10,198\n'
>>> list(csv.reader(s))[:5]
[[], ['/'], ['/'], ['d'], ['a']]
```

but you could have

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> list(csv.reader(StringIO(s)))[:5]
[[], ['//datestamp', 'SvcName', 'AvgSvcTime', 'MinSvcTime', 'MaxSvcTime', 'SvcVol'], ['2013-03-19 00:00:00', 'cfmeqdequeue', '1', '0', '10', '198'], ['2013-03-19 00:01:00', 'cfmeqdequeue', '1', '0', '10', '198']]
```

Note that you might want to call `.strip()` on your text to remove extraneous whitespace, especially if you want to use `DictReader` so you don't have to remember which column is which.